# How to block website from unauthorized users using MYSQL and JS

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have website which uses URL parameters e.g. `example.com?key=value`.

Let's imagine I have business card generator but besides parameters like name, surname. I want the user to provide a key to access it.

An example key can be `gI8ol3dAci`, I want my Javascript to check it before doing everything else. The key will be in a MySQL database table, I want to block IPs that entered wrong keys after 3 times and I want to store how many times key has been used. I was thinking about the following concept:

1. Check if IP is not blacklisted (3+ failed attempts)
2. Check if the key is working
3. Add 1 to count of uses of this key

The thing is I am not sure if it will be safe using JavaScript.

Comment: "_I am not sure if it will be safe using Javascript_" -> No. You cannot trust the client.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, I am beginner and only other thing I can think of is sending query with JS to PHP which will handle everything.